# Beautifulsoup webscraping.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from DnDbeyond. I am using Beautifulsoup and python and have been able to get some of the information that I need by using the "Div" tag and "Find_all" classes but I can't seem to find the info from these formatted blocks that contain the characters stats.

```
<div class="ct-skills__col--skill">Animal Handling</div>
```

I should be able to just be able to search for `soup.find("div", {"class": "ct-skills__col--skill"})`

right?

This is what my current code looks like.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/4741434')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "container"})
```

Which gets me

```
[<div class="container">
<div class="main content-container" id="content">
<section class="primary-content" role="main">
<div data-character-endpoint="/character/4741434/json" data-character-id="4741434" data-read-only="true" id="character-sheet-target"></div>
<script src="/Content/1-0-482-0/React/CharacterTools/dist/characterSheet.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</section>
</div>
</div>]
```

I know that my info is under "character-sheet-target" but I can't figure out how to get the info / class under there.

Sorry if this is rambely I didn't know how to explain this well.

Comment: This page is using Javascript on the client to generate the page.

Comment: Ok cool so is there a way to get that information?

Comment: Figured it out. Had to use Selenium to scrape the javascript stuff I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their json api, no need selenium, see the code below.

```
import requests
req = requests.get('https://www.dndbeyond.com/character/4741434/json')
print req.json()
```

Comment: I didn't know that that existed. That makes this way easier, thank you so much.

When I searched online I just saw a bunch of people saying maybe someday for an api and that one didn't exist yet.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly done fleshing out the entire structure.

Objective-C source include all class definitions.

https://github.com/mouser/BeyondDnD